# PHP DateTime: Incorrect display of days

Tags: php, datetime

I'm trying to create a time management system using PHP and Jquery.  I have been able to log clock-in, start-lunch, end-lunch, clock-out data into a database and retrieve that information per user. I'm adding the the difference between clock-in/start-lunch and end-lunch/clock-out, so that I can insert that value into the database.
So these are the values:

```
Clock-in: 2017-08-20 17:47:43  Start-Lunch: 0000-00-00 00:00:00
End-Lunch: 0000-00-00 00:00:00 Clock-out: 2017-08-24 11:50:09
```

The resulting interval is `015:05:37:52`

The seconds, minutes, and hours display correctly, but the days look crazy.  Days should be `4`, but it's saying 15?

Here's the php code down below:

```
$update = "UPDATE timeclock SET CLOCK_OUT = NOW() WHERE CLOCK_IN = ( SELECT * FROM (SELECT MAX(CLOCK_IN) FROM timeclock WHERE USERNAME = '$sessuser' order by USERNAME DESC Limit 1) t);";
$query = mysqli_query($dbc, $update);

$select = "SELECT CLOCK_IN, START_LUNCH, END_LUNCH, CLOCK_OUT FROM timeclock WHERE USERNAME = '$sessuser' ORDER BY CLOCK_IN DESC LIMIT 1;";
    $query1 = mysqli_query($dbc, $select) or die(mysqli_error($dbc));
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query1); 

    $clockin = $row["CLOCK_IN"];
    $startlunch = $row['START_LUNCH'];
    $endlunch = $row['END_LUNCH'];
    $clockout =  $row['CLOCK_OUT'];

    if($clockin !="0000-00-00 00:00:00" && $startlunch == "0000-00-00 00:00:00" && $endlunch == "0000-00-00 00:00:00" && $clockout != "0000-00-00 00:00:00") {
        echo $clockin . " " . $startlunch . "<br />";
        echo $endlunch . " " . $clockout . "<br />";

        $dateclockin = new DateTime($clockin);
        $datestartlunch = new DateTime($startlunch);
        $dateendlunch = new DateTime($endlunch);
        $dateclockout = new DateTime($clockout);

        $intval1 = date_diff($datestartlunch, $dateclockin);
        $intval2 = date_diff($dateendlunch, $dateclockout);

        $period1 = $intval1->format("%Y:%m:%d:%H:%I:%S");
        $period2 = $intval2->format("%Y:%m:%d:%H:%I:%S");

        echo $period1;
        echo $period2;

        function time_to_interval($time) {
            $parts = explode(':',$time);
            $parts[2] -= 1;

            //echo $parts[2];

            return new DateInterval('P' . $parts[2].'DT'.$parts[3].'H'.$parts[4].'M'.$parts[5].'S');
        }

        function add_intervals($a,$b) {
            $zerodate = new DateTime('0000-00-00 00:00:00');
            $dt = clone $zerodate;
            $dt->add($a);
            $dt->add($b);
            return $zerodate->diff($dt);
        }

        function format_interval_dhhmmss($interval){
            $totalhours =  0; //($interval->a);
            return $totalhours.$interval->format('%d:%H:%I:%S');
        }

        $interval1 = time_to_interval($period1);
        $interval2 = time_to_interval($period2);
        $interval3 = add_intervals($interval1,$interval2);

        $totalhrs = format_interval_dhhmmss($interval3);

        echo "This is total hours" . $totalhrs;

    }
```

Comment: I don't get it. Did someone have a four day long lunch break?

Comment: @Andreas lol. no.   Just logged in the system for four days.  It's in the event the user is classified as a part time "employee", doesn't come into the system every day, and forgets to logout.

Comment: ``$ClockOut = new DateTime('2017-08-24 11:50:09');
$ClockIn = new DateTime('2017-08-20 17:47:43');

$Interval = $ClockIn->diff($ClockOut);
echo $Interval->format("%Y:%m:%d:%H:%I:%S");`` output `00:0:3:18:02:26`